# How to extract the repeated word in a string?

Tags: algorithm

**Without providing code**, I would like to get an idea, how can I get the repeated word in a string, example: "HelloHelloHelloHello" the result is : "Hello"

Thank you

Comment: only repeated word can exist in string?

Comment: Yes only the repeated can exist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At a high level:

1. Find all divisors of the length of the string
2. For each divisor N, starting with the smallest, split the string into substrings of length N
3. Check if all substrings are equal
4. For the first divisor for which they are, take that as the answer

For your "HelloHelloHelloHello" example:

- All divisors: 1, 2, 4, 5, 10 (ignoring 20)
- For 1: `["H","e","l","l","o","H","e","l","l","o", ...]`

  - All substrings are not equal
- For 2: `["He","ll","oH", ...]`

  - All substrings are not equal
- For 4: `["Hell","oHel", ...]`

  - All substrings are not equal
- For 5: `["Hello", "Hello", ...]`

  - All substrings are equal. Done.

Comment: what about if there is this case : HelloHelloHelloHe?

Comment: What about it?? What's the question?

Comment: when the given string is for example : I am a string and the key is : Hello , the repeated string is : HelloHelloHel. so how can I know that the used key is Hello.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably not the most efficient or thorough way to accomplish this, but it should work nonetheless:

1. Start with iterating through the string with an index counter 'i' (start at index 1).
2. At each index 'i', look forward to index 'i + (i +1)'. If index 'i + (i +1)' equals index 'i', then there is a potential repeated word.
3. From there, substring from 0 to 'i' and check if that equals a substring from 'i + 1' to 'i + (i +1)'.
4. If it those substrings equal one another, you know you have a repeated word.
5. If they do not equal one another, you can continue to increment 'i' and checking step 2 -5.

Note: Be sure to check the bounds of your string, making sure you don't try to check an index out of bounds during any of these.